# Making template type LinkedList

Tags: c++, templates

i have recently started studying linkedlist in c++. Although i am finding it pretty confusing but i made some functions to insert and delete and element from the linkedlist.

The program worked fine with `int` data type. But i want to create a linkedlist of template type and i cannot understand how to do it.

I have tried to create a function to insert the node at the first position of link list but it gives me errors like access specifier needed before node etc ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class node
{
    public:
    T data;
    node *next;
};

template<class T>
class linklist
{
    public:
    node <int>*head;

    linklist()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    bool Is_Empty(node <T>*ptr)
    {
        if(ptr==NULL)
        {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void insert_at_head(T num)
    {
        if(Is_Empty(head))
        {
            node <T>*temp = new node; // error is on this line. it says access specifier needed before node.
            temp->data = num;
            head = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }

        else
        {
            node *temp = new node;
            temp->data = num;
            head = temp;
            temp->next = head->next;
        }

    }

    void show_list(node <T>*ptr)
    {
        cout<<"\nElements in the List are : ";
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    getch()
}
```

Comment: You have to consequently use `node<T>` instead of `node`. Also `getch()` in main is missing the semicolon.

Comment: if i change node<T> to node, it gives me error in class linklist, in line where i have declared head pointer of type node. the error says 'node' is not a type.

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood. It's vice versa. Don't use `node`. Use `node<T>` everywhere.

Comment: oh ok. I have used node<T> everywhere but the error remains in inset_at_head function in line after which i have added a comment. the error says that type-specifier is needed before node.

Comment: It compiles fine: [Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/UtrkRZ)

Comment: yeah , it does now but can someone please explain why and what was causing that error ?

Comment: Wrong syntax. Simple as that.

Comment: It is called linked list - not link list

Comment: @Vertexwahn You would think, i would have figured that out by now... :P Thanks for pointing it out anyways..